# what does ":" mean in the declaration of a struct

Tags: c++

I can't understand the part of code **“Point() : x(0), y(0) {}，Point(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}”.**.

Especially about the question, **":"** is used for what here?

thanks in advance!

```
 Definition for a point.
      struct Point {
          int x;
          int y;
          Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
          Point(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
      };
```

Comment: thank you, one mark, for a java programmer,  the syntax to declare a constructor is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

it is used to begin an initializer list

x will be initalized with a and y with b in this example.

It is compulsory for **const** members of a class or a struct to use initialize it through an initializer list

Answer (score 1):

`Point() : x(0), y(0) {}`  <-- this is a constructor that creats a point at `(0,0)` coordonates. 
`Point(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}` this is a constructor that creats a point at `(a,b)` coordonates. Where `a` and `b` are given as input by the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's the start of an initialiser list for the members of the class/struct. You can use it call constructors of the class members, like you're doing there.